# What can a lava-powered factory do?

Tags: lava

Suppose we can withdraw lava underground and pump it into a factory, what will the factory do? eg:

- Produce bricks and other building materials
- Extracting minerals
- Generating electricity
- Cooking

What other possible usages?

Comment: Hmm, that's a very broad question. I'm sure there are many possible answers. It's like asking, "what can I do with wood?" The answer is limited only by the creativity of the answerer.

Comment: Worse than that, you're basically asking "what can I do with heat?" At the very least you should narrow this down to focus on what a lava-powered factory could do that, say, a natural-gas powered factory couldn't. Otherwise this is far too broad.

Comment: You should play Dwarf Fortress, where magma is a high tier fuel for creating... stuff. I remember the golem-forge from Masterwork DF, but I doubt you had a fantasy scenario in mind....

Comment: That @ApproachingDarknessFish said: your question boils down to (pun intended) just that: "what can I do with heat?". Answer: too much to list here. You will quickly run into one very tangible problem though: what to do with all the left-over stone from when the lava cools.

Comment: Wouldn't a more realistic question be something along the lines of how much energy could a geothermal powered factory draw per day and how last it would be able to run? Usually if you have enough energy than you can do anything and I doubt the factory will be dealing with lava directly unless they really needed to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lava factories have many uses, but they are most essential for the world's safety, because they allow villains to be defeated in a climactic fight.

Notable examples:

- [Polymorphic metal androids, model T-1000](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLkm5XFX3C4)
- [Emo Jedi kids gone bad](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_on_Mustafar)

They also make for good disposal sites for garbage and evil rings of power.